# How can I create one large, overarching function given multiple smaller functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am building a computer simulation in which the user can create complex logic gates using building blocks like AND, OR, NOT and I would like the program to store the structure of the logic gate in a new function.

For example, XOR is a complex logic operation that looks like this in my function notation

AND( OR(x1, x2), NOT(AND(x1, x2)) )

where x1 and x2 are two boolean inputs. How can I generate a function like XOR(x1, x2) and be able to call it whenever I want. I don't want it hard coded in, I want to be able to generate it depending on what gates are being used and how they are connected.

Any ideas or thoughts or clarifying questions would be greatly appreciated!

xor returns true if one input is on but not if both are on.
[image: XOR logic gate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is considered "unsafe", but it is certainly the most direct and intuitive answer: use `eval()`:

```js
const AND = (a,b) => a&&b;
const OR  = (a,b) => a||b;
const NOT = a => !a;

const a=true; b=false;

eval("XOR=(a,b)=>AND(OR(a,b),NOT(AND(a,b)))");

console.log(XOR(a,b));
console.log(XOR(a,a));
console.log(XOR(b,a));
console.log(XOR(b,b));
```

This can of course be embedded in a function that carries out some preprocessing and "safety checks" before actually applying the `eval()`-function on the user-supplied function-definition-string.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function XOR(var1, var2) {
  return var1 !== var2;
}
```

Where `var1` and `var2` are booleans.

Or

```
function XOR(var1, var2) {
  return AND( OR(var1, var2), NOT(AND(var1, var2)) );
}
```

Comment: `var2 !== var2` should be `var1 !== var2`

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't want to have to hard code it in. That would get very impractical if I want to create a calculator or something with many inputs and many gates.

Comment: @bib Are you asking for a short way to write `AND( OR(x1, x2), NOT(AND(x1, x2)) )` or something like a Macro in C?

Comment: @Chris Happy no, I want the code to generate the function so that I don't have to write a new one each time I make a new gate.

Comment: xor was just an example

Comment: @bib could you give me an example of code generating a function in another instance? I don't understand what you mean by "generating" a function.